# bash redirection with a result of another command

Tags: bash, shell

This command works very well.

```
bash < <(echo 'ls')
```

How this code work?
I cannot understand internal process of this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<(echo 'stuff')` is called *process substitution*.  It uses a named pipe (or FIFO) to pipe the output from the command (although the exact mechanism is system dependant).  You can use this construct anywhere* that a file name can be used, so with:

```
program < <(command)
```

we are taking the output from *command* and passing it to the standard-input stream of *program*.

*anywhere:  some programs use a technique called *memory mapping* (see `man 2 mmap`) which cannot be used with named pipes.  A well written program will check the file type beforehand, unfortunately not all programs are well written....

Answer (score 5):

***<(anycmd)*** creates a temporary file with the output of ***anycmd***

***anycmd <*** is running ***anycmd*** with its stdin being fed from the file on the right side of the ***<***

So your command is equivalent to

```
tmpf=$(mktemp)
echo 'ls' > $tmpf
bash < $tmpf
unlink $tmpf
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo ls` produces `ls`. `<( ... )` creates a file that contains it. `<` sends this file to the standard input of `bash`, making `bash` run it.